# Filter columns if certain strings are contained and convert these columns' data type using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

For `iris` dataset, let's say if I need to convert columns `'Sepal.Length', 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width'`'s data type to character.

```
df <- iris %>% 
  mutate_at(c('Sepal.Length', 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width'), as.character)
str(df)
```

Out:

```
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: chr  "5.1" "4.9" "4.7" "4.6" ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: chr  "1.4" "1.4" "1.3" "1.5" ...
 $ Petal.Width : chr  "0.2" "0.2" "0.2" "0.2" ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

But instead of list the column names, I would like to filter columns in an alternative way, which means if certain strings (`'Petal', 'Length'` for cases above) are contained in columns names, then convert those column's data type to character. I'm able to filter these columns use code below:

```
iris %>% 
  select_at(vars(matches(paste(c('Petal', 'Length'), collapse='|'))))
```

Out:

```
Sepal.Length Petal.Length Petal.Width
1            5.1          1.4         0.2
2            4.9          1.4         0.2
3            4.7          1.3         0.2
4            4.6          1.5         0.2
......
149          6.2          5.4         2.3
150          5.9          5.1         1.8
```

Now my question is how could embedded `mutate_at(as.character)` to `select_at(vars(matches(paste(c('Petal', 'Length'), collapse='|'))))`? Or maybe we have other more concise solution for this question? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

A further question, as if columns containing **brackets**, for example, for the following edited iris data, I need to convert the columns type to char for these columns contains `(sepal)` or `(petal)`, it seems not working (since all 4 columns were converted to char).

```
iris %>% 
  rename(`length.sepal` = Sepal.Length,
         `width(sepal)` = Sepal.Width,  # need to convert to char
         `length.petal` = Petal.Length,
         `width(petal)` = Petal.Width) %>%  # need to convert to char
  mutate(across(matches("((sepal))|((petal))"), as.character)) %>% 
  glimpse
```

Out:

```
$ length.sepal   <chr> "5.1", "4.9", "4.7", "4.6", "5", "5.4", "4.6", "5", "4.4", "4.9", "5.4…
$ `width(sepal)` <chr> "3.5", "3", "3.2", "3.1", "3.6", "3.9", "3.4", "3.4", "2.9", "3.1", "3…
$ length.petal   <chr> "1.4", "1.4", "1.3", "1.5", "1.4", "1.7", "1.4", "1.5", "1.4", "1.5", …
$ `width(petal)` <chr> "0.2", "0.2", "0.2", "0.2", "0.2", "0.4", "0.3", "0.2", "0.2", "0.1", …
$ Species        <fct> setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa…
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr::across` and tidy-select syntax, in the example below `matches()` which allows us to use a regular expression to match column names.

```r
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  mutate(across(matches("(Petal)|(Sepal)"), as.character)) %>% 
  glimpse # for better printing

#> Rows: 150
#> Columns: 5
#> $ Sepal.Length <chr> "5.1", "4.9", "4.7", "4.6", "5", "5.4", "4.6", "5", "4.4"~
#> $ Sepal.Width  <chr> "3.5", "3", "3.2", "3.1", "3.6", "3.9", "3.4", "3.4", "2.~
#> $ Petal.Length <chr> "1.4", "1.4", "1.3", "1.5", "1.4", "1.7", "1.4", "1.5", "~
#> $ Petal.Width  <chr> "0.2", "0.2", "0.2", "0.2", "0.2", "0.4", "0.3", "0.2", "~
#> $ Species      <fct> setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, s~
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

Update:
This will also work with brackets and other special characters. However, if those special characters have a special meaning in regex terminology we need to escape them with `\\`:

```r
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  rename(`length.sepal` = Sepal.Length,
         `width(sepal)` = Sepal.Width,  # need to convert to char
         `length.petal` = Petal.Length,
         `width(petal)` = Petal.Width) %>%  # need to convert to char
  mutate(across(matches("(\\(sepal\\))|(\\(petal\\))"), as.character)) %>% 
  glimpse

#> Rows: 150
#> Columns: 5
#> $ length.sepal   <dbl> 5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0, 5.4, 4.6, 5.0, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, ~
#> $ `width(sepal)` <chr> "3.5", "3", "3.2", "3.1", "3.6", "3.9", "3.4", "3.4", "~
#> $ length.petal   <dbl> 1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, ~
#> $ `width(petal)` <chr> "0.2", "0.2", "0.2", "0.2", "0.2", "0.4", "0.3", "0.2",~
#> $ Species        <fct> setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa,~
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution, just a small typo error, it should be `'Petal', 'Length'` instead of `'Petal', 'Sepal'` in the OP, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: It seems not working when column names contains brackets, please check the updated part. Or maybe there are error in my code.

Comment: @ahbon: see my update!

Comment: Cool, thanks for your guide and helps!